# HTMLで画像が表示されないことに関して

Tags: html, windows-10, internet-explorer, ms-office

こんにちは
HTMLで同一フォルダ内に保存している画像•壁紙を貼る際に、エクスプローラーから開くと正常に画像が貼り付けられているのですが、Web上のOneDriveからだと画像が張り付いていない状態になり、相互リンクもこの場合作動しなくなります。同一フォルダ内なので相対パスで、と記載しています。
共有リンクのOneDriveから開くHTMLにだけ画像が表示されない原因はなんでしょうか

Comment: どういった環境、コードでその現象が出ているのかがわからないと、答えようがない質問です。ご自身で作成されたコードを可能な範囲で提示していただいた方がアドバイスが集まりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

おそらく「web サーバ上にアップロードして HTML がレンダリングされるのと同じように OneDrive 上でも表示されて欲しい」、という事かと思いますが、現状だと **出来ない** となりそうです。
(あくまでテキストファイルとして扱われる)

[OneDriveのHTMLファイルを表示できない - Microsoft コミュニティ](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/all/onedrive%E3%81%AE%EF%BD%88%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%8D/9992d5b2-2048-4035-8202-2d9f7648f758)

> ブラウザーの OneDrive から HTML ファイルが開けないのは仕様の様ですね。